# Câmera aparece com tela preta. Erro fail to connect to camera service

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Eu gostaria de abrir a câmera, porém sem os botões que aparecem normalmente, gostaria de adicionar meus próprios botões e atribuir funcionalidades a eles.

Pesquisei mas não achei nenhuma resposta. Os botões que vou adicionar vão apenas redirecionar para outra activity, não é nada muito complicado... o problema está em como faço para adicioná-los e remover os que já existem.

Tentei fazer mas agora da erro e a aplicação fecha:

```
public class BuscaProduto extends AppCompatActivity {

private SurfaceView preview = null;
private SurfaceHolder previewHolder = null;
private Camera camera;
private boolean inPreview = false;
private boolean cameraConfigured = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.busca_produto);

    preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    previewHolder = preview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (requestPermissionCamera(this)) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Erro", ex.getMessage());
        }
        startPreview();
    }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (inPreview) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        inPreview = false;
    }
}

private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result = null;
    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
            if (result == null) {
                result = size;
            } else {
                int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                if (newArea > resultArea) {
                    result = size;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (result);
}

private void initPreview(int width, int height) {
    if (camera != null && previewHolder.getSurface() != null) {
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("SurfaceCallback", "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
            alert(t.getMessage());
        }

        if (!cameraConfigured) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(width, height,
                    parameters);

            if (size != null) {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                cameraConfigured = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void startPreview() {
    if (cameraConfigured && camera != null) {
        camera.startPreview();
        inPreview = true;
    }
}

SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        initPreview(width, height);
        startPreview();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }
};


public boolean requestPermissionCamera(Context context) {
    int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA = 221;
    boolean res = true;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            res = false;
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

private void alert(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

erro:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2254)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
                                                                                  at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:374)
                                                                                  at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:344)
                                                                                  at br.ufop.socialmarket.BuscaProduto.onResume(BuscaProduto.java:53)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5324)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2254) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Como a tela fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SurfaceView` para a sua visualização da câmera como descreve a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) no site do próprio Android. Nas condições do Android 6.0(Api level 23) existe o [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) que trata-se da questão das permissões, que é bem interessante você dar lida e aprender mais.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <Button android:text="Freeze"
        android:id="@+id/someButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Em seguida na sua classe Main faça assim:

```
private SurfaceView preview=null;
private SurfaceHolder previewHolder=null;
private Camera camera=null;

private boolean inPreview=false;
private boolean cameraConfigured=false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.surface_view);

    preview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
    previewHolder = preview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    camera=Camera.open();
    startPreview();
}

SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // no-op -- wait until surfaceChanged()
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                               int format, int width,
                               int height) {
        initPreview(width, height);
        startPreview();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // no-op
    }
};

private void initPreview(int width, int height) {
    if (camera!=null && previewHolder.getSurface()!=null) {
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.wtf("teste","teste");
            Toast.makeText(MainViewPage.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        if (!cameraConfigured) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
            Camera.Size size=getBestPreviewSize(width, height,
                    parameters);

            if (size!=null) {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                cameraConfigured=true;
            }
        }
    }
}

private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
                                       Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result=null;

    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height) {
            if (result==null) {
                result=size;
            }
            else {
                int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
                int newArea=size.width*size.height;

                if (newArea>resultArea) {
                    result=size;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return(result);
}

private void startPreview() {
    if (cameraConfigured && camera!=null) {
        camera.startPreview();
        inPreview=true;
    }
}
```

## Permissões

Considerando o Android 6.0(Api level 23), é necessário adaptar este método abaixo no seu código, levando em conta que também na hora de colocar uma ação de captura de imagem é necessário dar permissão para escrita e leitura `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` e `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

```
public boolean requestPermissionCamera(Context context){
        int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA = 221;
        boolean res=true;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                res = false;
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);

            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

## Screenshot

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dê uma olhada [nesse projeto](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Preview/).

Comment: Eu tentei e está dando o erro: fail to connect to camera service. Atualizei o post com meu código

Comment: @Éowyn este erro está dando porque você não está dando permissão a sua câmera! Provavelmente você está usando Android 6.0.

Comment: @Éowyn como eu disse, esse erro está acontecendo porque você não está dando permissão da câmera ao seu app. Antes de fazer a programação de permissão, você pode testar dando permissão manualmente, que foi o que fiz e por isso eu tirei essa screenshot para você ver funcionando.

Comment: Havia testado em um dispositivo de API 19 e o targetSdkVersion no manifest estava definido como 22. Mas mudei pra 23 e tentei fazer a requisição de permissão mas o erro continua :(

Comment: @Éowyn foi o que aconteceu comigo aí dei a permissão manualmente e funfou.

Comment: Você rodou meu código igualzinho? Pq não quer dar certo de jeito nenhum, não aparece nenhuma permissão qnd vou mexer manualmente

Comment: @Éowyn eu fiz aqui um esquema para facilitar para você, mas amanha eu te ajudo se não conseguir. Vou postar um método na minha resposta para você adaptar.

Comment: Eu tentei adaptar e estava dando o mesmo erro, aí resolvi dar um clean project e a aplicação parou de parar de responder, mas agora a tela da câmera fica preta. Já estou me sentindo bem burra por não conseguir fazer o que vc fala

Comment: @Éowyn Eu adaptei o `requestPermissionCamera` no meu código, porém não quis postar direto para você ontem a noite (de propósito) para fazer você pensar um pouco. Tente mais um pouco, qualquer coisa quando eu chegar em casa, dou mais uma ajuda. Agora estou no job.

Comment: Deu certo! Desculpa a demora pra dar o retorno... era o mesmo erro do meu outro problema, estava usando as tags de permissão no lugar errado. Muito obrigada!

Comment: @Éowyn por nada! Precisar dê um grito aqui!